# How to set two types of variables for same method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I have a `ListView` with `two events,`

```
1 listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

2 listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

I need to create a single method for both event, but the problem is each event has different return types. I created a method `getListViewSelected(e)`

```
 private void getListViewSelected(KeyEventArgs e)
        {}
```

but in case `listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` the argument is Invalid. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please can you show your full code and not just the function headers.. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you aware that MouseClick is called when the mouse is clicked and KeyDown is called when a keyboard key is pressed?

Comment: Those two events are for handling completely different input types. Unless you truly know what you are doing, I would not recommend trying to treat them as the same thing.

Comment: You can always create method like `void DoSomething(EventArgs e)` call this from both and just check `if ( e is MouseEventArgs )`

Comment: you should explain what you want to achieve in your method `getListViewSelected` ?

Comment: What will `getListViewSelected` *do* with it's `e` parameter? If it depends on what type it is, then why are you trying to shoehorn two different behaviours into a single method? If it does nothing with that parameter, why does it have it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 methods. First two are the handlers that convert the data received from the fixed signatures to your general method parameters of the third. In the third you can implement the logic that needs to trigger for both.

```
    listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        getListViewSelected(MyDataType.FromMouseEventArgs(e));
    }
    listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        getListViewSelected(MyDataType.FromKeyEventArgs(e));
    }

    private void getListViewSelected(MyDataType data)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
```

An example of the MyDataType class:

```
public class MyDataType
{
     public string AnyThingOfInterest
     {
         get; set;
     }
     public static MyDataType FromKeyEventArgs(KeyEventArgs e)
     {
         return new MyDataType() { AnyThingOfInterest = e.ToString() };
     }
     public static MyDataType FromMouseEventArgs(MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         return new MyDataType() { AnyThingOfInterest = e.ToString() };
     }
}
```

Comment: what is `MyDataType` I couldn't get this.?

Comment: I'll add an example implementation to the answer. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but in this way you can generally get the property AnyThingOfInterest just filled with the ToString() value of both possible inputs. You should edit that to fit your needs.